# El Capitan Does Not Install

Tags: macos, install

I have downloaded the installer for El Capitan to my mac running Yosemite.  I have placed the installed in the applications folder and double clicked on it to run it.  The installer launches, asks me to agree to a bunch of stuff, asks me to login as admin, closes my open apps and prompts me to restart the mac.  Which I do.  This all seems like normal installer behavior to me.  However, once the mac restarts I am prompted to login, and then the installation never begins.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us more information? What computer do you have? What have you tried to resolve this issue? Have you checked any log files to see if the installer or OS reported a crash?

Comment: Where would I find the log files for an install attempt?  That seems like a great place to start!

Comment: I would attempt the instillation. When it fails, open the Console app (under Applications -> utilities). This will give you access to all the logs. My guess (though I'm not sure) is that the install logs will be on the System.log file. If they aren't, try looking for an install log file in the log folders (found on the left side of the console app).

Comment: I could not find any relevant logs where you mentioned so I am going to attempt this method: https://www.macissues.com/2015/10/01/how-to-overcome-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-not-installing/